# Left_join under condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, left-join

I have 2 dataframes and I need to merge them based on condition:

````
```
# Dataframe 1
plant1 <- c("FF",  "DO")
loc1 <- c("MM",  "KB")
df1 <-  data.frame(plant1,  loc1)
df1

  plant1  loc1
1    FF    MM
2    DO    KB

# Dataframe 2
plant2 <- c("FF",  "DO","DO")
loc2 <- c("MM",  "KB","KB")
name <- c("name_1",  "name_2","name_3")
frequency <- c(1, 2, 2)

df2 <-  data.frame(plant2,  loc2, name, frequency)
df2

      plant2 loc2   name      frequency
1     FF     MM     name_1         1
2     DO     KB     name_2         2
3     DO     KB     name_3         2

```
````

I need to bring to `df1` value of `name` from `df2` ONLY for those cases WHERE `frequency == 1`,
for the rest of the cases I need to set specific text.

This is the result I need to get:

```
  plant3  loc3    name3
1   FF     MM     name_1
2   DO     KB     multiple
```

I am starting with the simplest code, where I need to add that condition:

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by=c("plant1" = "plant2", "loc1" = "loc2" ))
```

Of course I can do it in "dirty" way by simple `left_join` and then replacing values in `name` column for `frequency` !=1 and adding `unique()`.

Is there more elegant way?

I was checking this discussion for the topic, but could not apply it for my case:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-join-two-tables-with-an-or-statement-in-r-using-dplyrs-join-functions/37633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a `data.table` possibility...

```
library(data.table)
# Make them data.tables
setDT(df1);setDT(df2)
# Set key for join
setkey(df1, plant1, loc1)
setkey(df2, plant2, loc2)
# Join
df2[df1, .(name3 = if (.N > 1) "multiple" else x.name), by = .EACHI][]
#    plant2 loc2    name3
# 1:     DO   KB multiple
# 2:     FF   MM   name_1
```

Comment: Hi @Wimpel, it is interesting solution, I did not use it in my practice yet, but I have an error:  `Error in `[.data.table`(df2, df1, .(name3 = if (.N > 1) "multiple" else x.name),  : 
  Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'character'. Column types must be consistent for each group.` I am not sure how to resolve it. Typeof `frequency` is double, all the rest columns are character.